# why get the html content.txt is empty?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrape

The target of the program is simple to get the headline of tageschau.de.
It normal at first, but it can get nothing after a few runs.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'
                          'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                          'Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
            'Host': 'www.tagesschau.de',
            'Referer': 'https://www.tagesschau.de/'
          }

# get and parse the HTML of tageschau.de
URL = 'https://www.tagesschau.de/'
html = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
html_parse = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'lxml')

# find all headline in homepage
elements = html_parse.find_all('h4',{'class':'headline'})
for element in elements:
    print(element.txt)
```

It got nothing.

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

But when I use `element` instead of `element.txt`, there are some right output

```
<h4 class="headline"><a href="/multimedia/livestreams/livestream3/">Live: tagesschau24</a></h4>
<h4 class="headline"><a href="/100sekunden/">100 Sekunden</a></h4>
<h4 class="headline"><a href="/multimedia/sendung/ts-39833.html">tagesschau 20 Uhr</a></h4>
<h4 class="headline"><a href="/multimedia/sendung/ts-39841.html">Letzte Sendung</a></h4>
<h4 class="headline">++ Fauci warnt vor "einer Menge Leid" ++</h4>
<h4 class="headline">Weniger Party, mehr Wellness</h4>
<h4 class="headline">November-Lockdown kostet 19 Milliarden</h4>
```

It makes me so confused, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the innertext of element try `.text`:

```
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

For innerHTML use `.html`:

```
for element in elements:
    print(element.html)
```